# Simplifying Long List of `if` Statements

Tags: python-2.7

I have a lot of page objects for an application I am testing. The page object have all of the elements on the page. I am writing a `validate_fields` method on each page object so that when another tester navigates to the page, they can call this `validate_fields` method to verify that all of the items which are supposed to be on the page are in fact on the page.

The problem I am running into is that this `validate_fields` function can be really really long, and it is just a bunch of

```
if not x.is_displayed():
    self.problems.append("The item X is missing from the page")
```

With problems being a list of problems which we assert is empty at the end of our test.

Below is a code sample, is there a way to simplify this?

```
def validate_fields(self):
    if not self.el_page_header.is_displayed():
        self.problems.append("The Page Header is missing")
    if not self.el_preferred.is_displayed():
        self.problems.append("The Preferred check box is missing")
    if not self.el_address.is_displayed():
        self.problems.append("The Address 1 field is missing")
    if not self.el_address_2.is_displayed():
        self.problems.append("The Address 2 field is missing")
    if not self.el_address_3_city.is_displayed():
        self.problems.append("The Address 3 City field is missing")
    if not self.el_address_4_state.is_displayed():
        self.problems.append("The Address 4 State field is missing")
    if not self.el_address_5_zip_code.is_displayed():
        self.problems.append("The Address 5 Zip Code field is missing")
    if not self.el_contact.is_displayed():
        self.problems.append("The Contact field is missing")
    if not self.el_phone.is_displayed():
        self.problems.append("The Phone field is missing")
    if not self.el_phone_ext.is_displayed():
        self.problems.append("The Phone Extension field is missing")
    if not self.el_fax.is_displayed():
        self.problems.append("The Fax number field is missing")
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put all those widgets along with their human-readable name into a list:

```
def validate_fields(self):
    widgets = [(self.el_page_header, "Page Header"),
               (self.el_preferred, "Preferred check box"), 
               ... and many more... ]
    for widget, name in widgets:
        if not widget.is_displayed():
            self.problems.append("The %s is missing" % name)
```

Comment: worked superbly, thank you very much. Certainly cleaned up my page object a lot.